# How to convert Navigation-based iPhone app to TabBar-based app

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've an iPhone app that is a navigation-based app.

The customer require to convert 60% of the app to be inside a global TabBar. (i.e. to include one tabbar in 60% from the app views)

So, what is the best practice to follow here?
Is it to include a TabBar using IB into the `Window`?
Or add change the navigation code cross the whole app and push a TabBarController instead of the regular ViewController?

Please provide me with ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used a new window-based application and put the following code:

The idea is that to create a UITabBarController and put on it the NavigationController instead of the ViewControllers.

And each navigationController will navigate to its own set of ViewContrllers.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController* tabBarContoller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    Cross1VC* cross1VC = [[Cross1VC alloc]initWithNibName:@"Cross1VC" bundle:nil];
    cross1VC.title = @"Cross 1";
    UINavigationController* crossNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:cross1VC];
    crossNav.title = @"Cross";
    [cross1VC release];

    Part1VC* part1VC = [[Part1VC alloc]initWithNibName:@"Part1VC" bundle:nil];
    part1VC.title = @"Part 1";
    UINavigationController* partNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:part1VC];
    partNav.title = @"Part";
    [part1VC release];


    NSArray* viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:crossNav, partNav, nil];
    [tabBarContoller setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];

    //tabBarContoller.delegate = [[SomeDelegateHandlerClass alloc]init]; // assign, not retain

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarContoller.view];
    //[tabBarContoller release]; // make instance variable and release in dealloc
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```